# How to get the raid controller make and model on a IBM Server?

Tags: raid-controller

I currently have a IBM IBM eserver xSeries 346 with Windows Server and according to device manager it has a IBM eserver xSeries 346 IBM ServerRaid 7k controller. How can I get the make and model? to see how many raids it support. Can someone tell how to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to do this, either on the server or remotely:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName server01`

```
Partitions : 4
DeviceID   : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Model      : DELL PERC 6/i SCSI Disk Device
Size       : 2097150289920
Caption    : DELL PERC 6/i SCSI Disk Device

Partitions : 1
DeviceID   : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
Model      : DELL PERC 6/i SCSI Disk Device
Size       : 301045248000
Caption    : DELL PERC 6/i SCSI Disk Device
```